# How to prevent Jmeter5.5 from stopping internet?

Tags: jmeter

I am doing some benchmark testing. During this, I have to increase numbers of users 3000, keeping ramp-up time 100 and loop count 1.
Somehow jmeter giving the below errors:

**Response code: Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException**

**Response message: Non HTTP response message: Connection to https://the-homepage-I-am-testing.net refused**

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no such thing as "JMeter5.5" yet, the latest version as of now is [JMeter 5.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-5.1)
2. Looking into error details it looks like a [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing) on the application under test side so you need to inspect what's causing these connections refusals:

   - inspect your application logs for any suspicious entries, it might be a matter of a [thread pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool) maximum setting which is not sufficient
   - inspect your application server / database configuration as it might be the case you have the above limitation on the middleware level
   - inspect OS configuration for the same as it might be the case there is not enough maximum open handles so OS cannot allocate a [socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket) to serve the connection
   - make sure to monitor baseline health metrics, application under test should have enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, etc. - you can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) for this
3. Looking into your configuration it doesn't necessarily assume 3000 concurrent users as you have only 1 iteration. Given 100 seconds ramp-up it might be the case that some users have already finished test execution and some had not been yet started. Double check you're really deliver the anticipated load using i.e. [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener.